# mysql select this formula E < X <=2E & X > 3E

Tags: mysql, select, formula

is it possible to select using this formula (E < X <=2E) & (X > 3E) by below query? Actually this formula for overdue categories.

```
select 
  ref_no, created_date, due_date, finish_date, curdate(), 
  DATEDIFF(due_date, curdate()) AS OverDueDays,
  DATEDIFF(due_date, created_date) AS RefDays 
from 
  ref_no_table 
where 
  DATE(NOW()) > due_date AND 
  approved_date is null AND 
  created_date like '2019-11%';
```

X = OverDueDays
E = RefDays 14

Thanks

Comment: There is no value of `X` that satisfies this equation unless `E` is negative.

Answer (score 0):

its easier to use `subquery` for your computed `dates` columns.

```
select t1.* from 
    (select 
      ref_no, created_date, due_date, finish_date, curdate(), 
      datediff(due_date, curdate()) AS OverDueDays,
      datediff(due_date, created_date) AS RefDays 
    from 
      ref_no_table 
    where 
      date(now()) > due_date and
      approved_date is null and
      created_date like '2019-11%') t1
where RefDays < OverDueDays and OverDueDays <= date_add(RefDays, interval 2 day)
    and OverDueDays > date_add(RefDays, interval 3 day)
```

Comment: I'm referring to 2E so additional 2 days of E

Comment: it should be the same.

Comment: yes.. issue solved.. just change to ( * ) instead of date_add.. tq